# Compose: recompose or redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React application which also uses [Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) and [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

Both of them has a `compose` function with very similar content:

- [Compose from Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/3e114f8c0fd4461e2f642c2737d2fa8297484728/src/compose.js)
- [Compose from Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/6ea33b60bcff1f793b0237420b7eee134624183c/src/packages/recompose/compose.js)

As far as they both do the same, I'd like to have only one module in my bundle.

Is there any known possible issue if I would like to use compose from redux to compose high order components from `recompose`?

Comment: There shouldn't be, they are both using the same known pattern, so if there is a difference one of them is buggy. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Semantically, they're both absolutely the same. But don't do it.**

---

I would argue against replacing one's library function with another. 
Let's say you use redux's compose instead of recompose's compose.

1. If the author of recompose updates his compose function and is
   different from redux, you lose.
2. If the author of redux updates his compose and it is not compatible with
   recompose, you lose.
3. If you decide to get rid of redux or recompose, you lose.

I would rather have more modules and keep my libraries decoupled.

Comment: Well, you right, when I have only recompose HOCs. But what to do if I also have `withRouter` from react-router and `connect` from `react-redux`?

Comment: because connect is from react-redux, you should use redux's compose there.
on the other hand, where recompose's functionality is used, stick with recompose's function. 
try to use compose function with its corresponding library. Your general train of thought should be: "If one of the three points above is true, would my app still run?"

Comment: Thank you, your question to myslef resolves my doubts.

Comment: glad to see you happy;-)